# Entity Framework - Foreign keys and Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I need your help understanding relationships between tables. I´m having a hard time trying to understand the usage/need of using navigation properties with foreign key properties to define relantionships.
Given the 2 classes below,

```
public class Person
{
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Package
{
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Account { get; set; }

        public Guid ShipperId { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Shipper { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid ReceiverId { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Receiver { get; set; }

}
```

If I try to update the database, I get the error

*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_' on table 'Packages' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.*

On the other hand if I remove the property `public Guid ....Id { get; set; }`, the database is created with the foreign keys but the `[Required]` annotation as no effect.

What´s the difference between including a `Guid` property and not?

Comment: Did you try to put `[ForeignKey("AccountId")]` on `Account` property? Here is [the tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: And also, could you share your Fluent Api configuration?

Comment: There are two `Id` properties. Which one did  you remove? I guess it's the one in `Person`. Please read about the differences in (foreign key) [relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) and [owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities).

Comment: After having done that, please note that there's are tons of questions about this SQL Server limitation on foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this classes:

```
 public class Person
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Package.Account))]
        public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }

    }

    public class Package
    {
        
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
       
        [ForeignKey(nameof(AccountId))]
        [InverseProperty("Packages")]
        public virtual Person Account { get; set; }
    }
```

and use this code in dbcontext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Package>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Person)
    .WithMany(p => p.Packages)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AccountId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

});
```